# Can't write binary file in python

Tags: python, file, text, binary, precision

I need to write a binary file in python where first few lines are 8 byte ints and the rest a bunch of double precision numbers. How do I best do it? I tried this code, but I got stuck, becuase for some reason, this code generates **only** text files despite being open in wb.

```
if binary:
            outfile = open(filename,"wb")
            text = f"1\n8\n{nrcells}\n{nrspecs}\n"
            outfile.write(text.encode(encoding="UTF-8"))
            if self.rho.ndim == 3:
                for x3 in range(self.par["rho_dim"][2]):
                    for x2 in range(self.par["rho_dim"][1]):
                        text="\n".join(f"{d:.8e}" for d in self.rho[:, x2, x3]*10**(-10))+"\n"
                        outfile.write(text.encode(encoding="UTF-8"))
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as file contents? You are explicitly writing UTF-8 encoded text. Do you expect your 8 byte integers to occupy 8 bytes in the file? Adding newlines into the mix doesn't make sense in that case, because one of the bytes may contain the decimal value `10`, which corresponds to a newline, effectively breaking your file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write binary data, it's not enough to just open the file in binary mode.

When you are executing these lines

```py
text = f"1\n8\n{nrcells}\n{nrspecs}\n"
outfile.write(text.encode(encoding="UTF-8"))
```

you are still writing textual data to it.

Instead, you may want to have a look at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) and [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) standard library modules. They enable you to write your numerical data to `bytes` objects or files in binary modes.

To write your `1, 8, nrcells, nrspecs` header, assuming they are 8 byte integers, you'd do something like this:

```py
# q means "long long", or 8 bytes signed integer
header_bytes_content = struct.pack('qqqq', 1, 8, nrcells, nrspecs)  
outfile.write(header_bytes_content)
```

To write your float values, you could either write them one by one:

```py
# d means 8 byte floating point; f means 4 byte floating point
float_bytes_content = struct.pack('d', float_value)
outfile.write(float_bytes_content)
```

or gather all the values into an array and write them to the file:

```py
float_array = array.array('d', float_values)
float_array.tofile(outfile)
```

To read it back out of the file, you can use `struct.unpack` and `array.fromfile`

Note that, if you don't *need* the file to be binary, you probably *shouldn't* use a binary format. Textual formats are easier to read and write by code and humans, and usually don't take up much more space.